# how to execute more than one commands in bat file?

Tags: batch-file, jasperserver

I am trying to build jasperserver. I want to execute all those commands through bat file. I have created one bat file but when I execute it, it executes only first command.

```
@Echo Off
js-ant clean-config 
js-ant gen-config 
js-ant add-jdbc-driver 
js-ant build-pro 
js-ant create-js-db 
js-ant build-js-ddl-pro 
js-ant init-js-db-pro 
js-ant import-sample-data-pro
```

these are the content of bat file.. I am not sure what to do... I never created bat file :)
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess js-ant is a batch file itself. In that case you need to `CALL` it, otherwise the calling batch file is terminated automatically.

This should work:

```
@Echo Off
call js-ant clean-config 
call js-ant gen-config 
call js-ant add-jdbc-driver 
call js-ant build-pro 
call js-ant create-js-db 
call js-ant build-js-ddl-pro 
call js-ant init-js-db-pro 
call js-ant import-sample-data-pro
```